# How do you restate setInterval after clearInterval has already been declared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I realize there are more than a few answers on here about this but this particular instance has a very individual problem. I need to, on click, replay this png sequence after clearInterval has been used.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");

var animationArray = ['assets/calvin_hobbes_dance00.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance01.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance02.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance03.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance04.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance05.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance06.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance07.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance08.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance09.png',
                    'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance10.png'];

var animationIndex = 0;

function changeImage () {

  myImage.setAttribute("src", animationArray[animationIndex]);
  animationIndex++;

  if (animationIndex >= animationArray.length) {
    animationIndex = 10;
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    }
}

  var intervalHandler =  setInterval(changeImage, 100);
```

A secondary question, this is merely a code sample. How might I wrap this so I can use it for elements that have animations attached that when upon focus play the animation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `onclick` handler to your image. In the `onclick` handler, reset the `animationIndex` to 0, call `clearInterval` to clear the interval if it is running, and call the `setInterval` function again.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");

var animationArray = ['assets/calvin_hobbes_dance00.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance01.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance02.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance03.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance04.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance05.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance06.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance07.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance08.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance09.png',
                'assets/calvin_hobbes_dance10.png'];

var animationIndex = 0;

function changeImage () {

  myImage.setAttribute("src", animationArray[animationIndex]);
  animationIndex++;

  if (animationIndex >= animationArray.length) {
    animationIndex = 10;
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
  }
}

myImage.onclick = function() {
  animationIndex = 0;
  clearInterval(intervalHandler);
  intervalHandler =  setInterval(changeImage, 100);
};

var intervalHandler =  setInterval(changeImage, 100);
```

To answer your secondary question, you might want to consider another approach because this could get kind of messy and be hard to maintain in the future. Consider learning how to do animations using HTML canvas. Here is a tutorial I found showing how you could create multiple animations: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

In fact, I would advise to change your implementation to use the canvas instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the click handler also call `clearInterval()`, in case the previous animation is incomplete? (Either that or test the current value of `animationIndex` before resetting it, and not call `setInterval()` if an animation is in progress since resetting `animationIndex` would restart the current animation using its current interval.)

Comment: Any idea how to keep this from auto playing till it has focus?

Comment: Also now there's a problem where after each click the speed rapidly increases no matter the elapsed time between each click. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: @NickNutting I updated my answer based on nnnnnn's feedback. You need to call `clearInterval` inside the onclick function because it will create another interval which will make the animation go faster.

Comment: @NickNutting What do you mean when you say "focus"? Do you want it to stop playing when you click somewhere else?

Comment: That's so interesting. Thanks for your help on this. It is immensely appreciated. What I was asking with the focus is that I don't want the animation to play automatically on the page. I would rather see it play on focus of the element. Then after that you can click to watch it replay again. Does that make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: @NickNutting If you want it to play only when you click it, then you just have to remove the last line. The `var intervalHandler =  setInterval(changeImage, 100);`. That is the thing that is causing to run on page load.

Comment: Killing that last line was exactly what I needed actually. How would you recommend throwing this into a canvas? Just wrap the img tag in a canvas tag?

Comment: @NickNutting No you can't use HTML elements in a canvas. Using canvas is a whole other animal. You have to do all the programming to render and animate it yourself. Click the link to the tutorial. They explain it better there.